# How to dynamiclly change param in application.properties so that can use new value to trigger schedule job

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a application(here i call it Start-Common) that only send heartbeat info to mongodb, it use `@ConditionalOnProperty` and `@ConditionalOnClass` to get heartbeat info and MongoTemplate.

```
@EnableScheduling
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = {"b2b.fwk2.service.name", "server.port", "server.remark"})
@ConditionalOnClass(value = MongoTemplate.class)
public class HeartbeatScheduler {

    @Autowired
    private MongoTemplate template;

    @Value("${b2b.fwk2.service.name}")
    private String service;

    private volatile String status = "active";

    @Value("${server.port}")
    private int port;

    @Value("${server.remark}")
    private String remark;
```

And I have another application to depend on Start-Common, and set config in application.properties and prepare MongoDB dependency, so that once it start, it would send heartbeat info to mongodb by Start-Common

Now I want to add a config param in application.properties which depend on some if-else check.

How to add it and also can make the Start-Common receive this config param?

Thanks a lot !~~~

Comment: you do know that if this is already built in when you are using mongodb and spring? https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.1.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/mongo/MongoHealthIndicator.java

Answer (score 0):

You can use **FileChangedReloadingStrategy** in the Spring configuration.

Here's an example:

[Link](https://github.com/saumitra56/spring-boot-sample/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/utils/ReloadableProperties.java)